# Why is only one 'data' event emitted when stdout exceeds the buffer size?

Tags: node.js, sockets, stream, buffer, stdout

Background: https://github.com/Almenon/AREPL-vscode/pull/332
(It's a lot, I suggest reading below first)

I'm assuming node flushes stdout when the [highWaterMark](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/stream.html#stream_buffering) is reached. Is this correct? It looks like the answer is yes according to  this [stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627538/when-does-node-emit-a-data-event). Assuming so, if the high water mark is surpassed the extra characters should come in a second flush, right?

Node appears to be ignoring the high water mark and only flushing once, regardless of buffer size.

Sample code reproducing my problem with expected / actual result:

```js
import { spawn } from "child_process"

// 8192*2 (16384 aka 16KB) is the highWaterMark (aka buffer size?)
const node_process = spawn("node", ["-e", "process.stdout.write('a'.repeat(8192*2+1));setTimeout(()=>{console.log('done')},4000)"])

node_process.on('error', err => console.error(err))

let numFlushes = 0
node_process.stdout.on('data', (buffer: Buffer) => {
    numFlushes += 1
    const str = buffer.toString()
    console.log(`flush number: ${numFlushes}\
    Buffer length: ${buffer.length}`)
    if (buffer.length < 20) console.log(str)
})

/*
Expected result: 3 flushes, one when highWaterMark is reached, another with rest of stdout, final with done log
Acutal result: 2 flushes. All of stdout is recieved at once. 4 seconds later comes the done log.
Related docs: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/stream.html#stream_buffering
OUTPUT (courtesy of quokka)
flush number: 1    Buffer length: 16385
  at ​​​`flush number: ${ numFlushes }\ Buff...​​​ ​personal/test_node_buffer.ts:11:4
flush number: 2    Buffer length: 11
  at ​​​`flush number: ${ numFlushes }\ Buff...​​​ ​personal/test_node_buffer.ts:11:4
done
  at ​​​str​​​ ​personal/test_node_buffer.ts:13:8
*/
```

https://gist.github.com/Almenon/6286ca1baf0714b56dc133e03728eb12

I have been testing this on Windows 10.
On linux if you do *8+2 it has 3 flushes as expected. Odd.
Other than that both platforms have the same behavior.

https://repl.it/@almenon/testBufferSize

Comment: With a `process.stdout.write()` that large, you may have triggered an error in the `.write()`.  You would need to install a listener for the `error` event on `process.stdout` or use a callback for the `.write()` to see.  Streams don't have infinite buffering capabilities for arbitrarily large writes.  They likely draw the line somewhere.

Comment: Also, code required to understand your question should be pasted into the question itself.  It's good to offer a link to more supporting code or a complete implementation like you did, but for a variety of reasons, the code necessary to see the main issue should be pasted into your question directly.  This is because external links have a habit of breaking or changing over time, rendering the question useless as a long term reference.  Pasting the code into the question also allows it to be indexed for searching and viewed more efficiently by mobile users.

Comment: @jfriend00 I tried adding a listener for the error event but I didn't see any error. I've also moved the code into the question itself.

Comment: When I run your code with some more debugging in it, there are no errors.  All the output comes at once.  When I step through the `process.stdout.write()`, it just writes the whole amount without buffering at all.  The highWaterMark is used to determine whether the `.write()` will return `false` or not, indicating that no more `writes()` can be done until the `drain` event, but it is not used to make it into two writes.

Comment: Hey, maybe the problem is the system command line buffer? Check this: 

`const node_process = spawn("stdbuf", ["-o", "0", "node" "-e", "process.stdout.write('a'.repeat(8192*2+1));setTimeout(()=>{console.log('done')},4000)"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33465

Node emits data events "when it feels like it"

Yes, that is seriously the answer.